# Trying to access userid after login on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to access userid within a plugin after someone logs in in WordPress so that I can assign the stuff they did with their session to that userid in a custom table.

I've got this:

```
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'orr_gamify_save_session_to_user');
```

I'd also tried:

```
add_action('wp_login', 'orr_gamify_save_session_to_user');
```

But that did not work either.

Then the function is:

```
function orr_gamify_save_session_to_user() {
    global $wpdb,$current_user;

    if(!session_id())
        {
        session_start();
        }

    $UserID = $DataToUpdate[UserID] = get_current_user_id();
    $SessionID = $WhereToUpdate[SessionID] = session_id();

    $TableName = "wp_gamify";
    if($UserID != 0)
        {   
        if($wpdb->update($TableName,$DataToUpdate,$WhereToUpdate))
            {
            #print '<div class="alert alert-success fade in"><strong>Attempting...</strong> User '.$UserID.' for Sesssion '.$SessionID.'</div>';
            #print '<div class="alert alert-success fade in"><strong>Success!</strong> We\'ve assigned your progress to your account.</div>';
            }
        else
            {
            #print '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><strong>Failed!</strong> We were unable to save your progress to your account.</div>';
            }
        }
}
```

It updates, but it was giving me a UserID of zero.

Comment: So your function get's fired, the DB get's updated, but the variable UserID = 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_login](http://hookr.io/actions/wp_login/) accepts 2 parameters if you define the number of arguments in the add_action function. 10 refers to the priority and 2 to the number of arguments.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'orr_gamify_save_session_to_user', 10, 2);
```

$user is a [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) class. so you can just use the ID of it.

```
function orr_gamify_save_session_to_user($user_login, $user) {
  $UserID = $DataToUpdate["UserID"] = $user->ID;
```

Don't forget the quotes to define the key of an array.

```
$UserID = $DataToUpdate["UserID"] = $user->ID;
$SessionID = $WhereToUpdate["SessionID"] = session_id();
```

Comment: Thanks TeeDeJee! I tried to do the 2 parameters in the orr_gamify_save_session_to_user function but it gave me an error. I was able to make the $user global and then pull it in that way.

Thanks also for the tip to use quotes to define the key of the arrays.

Comment: @James I forgot a part in my code. I updated the add_action part with the priority and arguments. Then it will accept my code. Can you try it and let me know?